# Override jQuery Mobile Background CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to override the typical jQuery Mobile background with a `.jpg`.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out.  It is driving me nuts!  I have been all over SO and Google to no avail with anyone's answers.
My current header information

```
<head>
    <title>Veolia Water Splash Guide</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylo.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

The process my application is following:

1. `index.html` loads as a picture fades in. (This CSS override works perfect)
2. After the image has faded in, I do a `$.mobile.changePage()` to another page, ***not*** a multipage format
3. This is where it fails, the background loads up, but then gets overridden by something.  I just cannot seem to figure out what is overriding it.

This is my CSS

```
#logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

body
{
    background: url('../img/background.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
    background-position:center center !important;
    background-attachment:scroll !important;
    background-size:100% 100% !important;
}

.ui-page .ui-body-c .ui-page-active .ui-overlay-c .ui-mobile-viewport
{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Anyone have some pointers or know what I am doing wrong?  The background flashes for a split second, but then gets tossed out...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need commas between the CSS classes you are setting to transparent. Next, as ui-overlay-c is also applied to the body, you can set its background image along with the body's.

So together, set the transparency first, then the body background:

```
.ui-page, .ui-body-c, .ui-page-active, .ui-overlay-c, .ui-mobile-viewport
{
    background: transparent !important;
}

body, .ui-overlay-c
{
    background: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/wallpapers/digital_layers-1440x900.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
    background-position:center center !important;
    background-attachment:scroll !important;
    background-size:100% 100% !important;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle of the above:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5GgR9/